# c struct queue error: "array type has incomplete element type"

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to implement a simple priority queue from array of queues. I'm trying to define a struct queue, and than a struct priority queue that has an array of queues as its member variable. However, when I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

> pcb.h:30: error: array type has incomplete element type

The code is below:

```
typedef struct{
    pcb *head;
    pcb *tail;
    SINT32 size;
} pcb_Q;

typedef struct {
 struct pcb_Q queues[5];
 SINT32 size;
} pcb_pQ;
```

Could someone give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cite an error on line 30.  But don't provide enough context to know the line numbers.  Please make the line-numbering clear, and make sure you include line 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
 pcb_Q queues[5];
 SINT32 size;
} pcb_pQ;
```

Your struct type has no name.  Only the typedef is called `pcb_Q`.

Answer (score 3):

You already typedef the pcb_Q, no need to use struct keyword any more.
Just use this:

```
typedef struct { 
    pcb_Q queues[5]; 
    SINT32 size; 
} pcb_pQ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this line:

```
struct pcb_Q queues[5];
```

Which references structure pcb_Q.

You have not defined pcb_Q as a structure.
Instead, you typedef'd pcb_Q as a new type (which happens to be an un-named struct).

Try this instead:

```
pcb_Q queues[5];
```